# Fatal error: Class 'Configure' not found in ..\cakephp\2.3\lib\Cake\bootstrap.php

Tags: cakephp

**Error message:**

```
Fatal error: Class 'Configure' not found in C:\wamp\cakephp\2.3\lib\Cake\bootstrap.php on line 163
```

I have seen other answers on this issue ([like this one](https://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2764-fatal-error-class-configure-not-found-in-varwwwmypostmaillibcakebootstrapphp-on-line-142)), all hinting at ensuring I am not missing any files, but I have added all files and folders from a fresh download of [CakePHP v.2.3 via Github](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp).

Can anyone shed any light on why I am still getting an error like this?

Key lines of code shown below:

**webroot/index.php**

```
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', '../../../cakephp/2.3/lib');
}

if (!defined('CORE_PATH')) {
    if (function_exists('ini_set') && ini_set('include_path', CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . PATH_SEPARATOR . ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path'))) {
        [...]
        define('CORE_PATH', null);
    } else {
        [...]
        define('CORE_PATH', CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS);
    }
}
```

**lib/Cake/bootstrap.php**

```
App::uses('Configure', 'Core');

Configure::bootstrap(isset($boot) ? $boot : true);
```

Comment: Why do you manually define your CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH? If you dont do that, cake will automatically do that for you.

Comment: It is an upgrade to a slightly customised build. That statement was there already although notice that it only defines it if it isn't already defined.

Comment: Note that it only sets the include path correctly if you didnt customize it.

Comment: In my WAMP configuration, I have `cakephp/2.3/...` outside of my `www/` directory if that helps explain it maybe?

Comment: Update: I seem to have got this working to a certain extent although I am still getting multiple errors with the debugger set to 1 or 2

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have an old version of index.php

Use the current one available at github.

It contains

```
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {}
```

instead of your

```
if (!defined('CORE_PATH')) {}
```

Comment: Thanks @mark, I have updated my index.php file to the latest release as well but it seems I am having problems connecting to the core files again. I'm convinced it's something I've removed unknowingly but will keep looking. Thanks again

Comment: As I mentioned above: Note that it only sets the include path correctly if you didnt customize it. Otherwise you need to manually set your include path here.

Answer (score 0):

Where is DocumentRoot pointing to ?

If you load (e.g.) /index.php then your include_path could be incorrect and one directory too deep.
Use instead:

```
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', '../../cakephp/2.3/lib');
}
```